# How to arrange SCNnodes in stack in scenekit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

I want to arrange my nodes like a stack. I have many nodes in my project. The Position is given by dynamically so we can not arrange it in a stack by hardcoding the positions. So how can I arrange the nodes like a stack in scenekit?

Comment: i.Ex. you could organize them in an Array.... or can you provide more information about your goal?

Comment: the node position is coming from JSON, also we can not say how many nodes would be there. So can we change the Y position accordingly with every node

Comment: whereever the position comes from, if you put your nodes in an array, you can count them at any time or modify all the positions using some for-loop. can you post some code for better undertanding?